# Got a Playstation Classic (PS1) and Games list shows two icons for it, is it safe to delete one?

Tags: ps3, psn

I recently installed Chrono Cross from the Playstation store to my PS3, but there are two icons in the list now, if I click one it installs the game again, the other one is the actual game. They look similar and like half the time I click the one that re-installs the game instead of the one that starts it. When I select the option to delete, it warns me that it will be uninstalled, but I wonder if that means the game will be uninstalled, or the installer will be uninstalled. Is it safe to delete the 'install' one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to delete the one that "installs" the game, it says "uninstall" because the installer itself is an application that runs and installs the game in your PS3.

Answer (score 3):

The one that installs the game exists only to copy the game to your PSP or PS Vita. It can be safely deleted once you have done so or if you do not plan to do so. It's just a weird side effect of how they handle installers, since the "real" PS1 game on PS3 doesn't let you copy it direct to PSP.